# Algolia not working on laravel development server

Tags: laravel, algolia

I integrated my laravel application with algolia.

The data syncing works well if I run my application by typing localhost/applicationname/public

but I get an error that says impossible to connect to algolia if I run the application through the php artisan serve command,(127.0.0.1:8000)

my save method looks like:

```
$model = new Model;
$model->name = 'name';
$model->save();
```

I've specified my algolia application id, and secret in my env file

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your Algolia configuration by configuring

`ALGOLIA_SEARCH_HOST=127.0.0.1:8000` on

`algolia.php` => `algolia.search.hosts`

if this error persists, try running your app witha  different web server such as `Apache` or `Nginx`